# Microsoft Graph API truncates personal notes (Outlook contacts)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am programming an appplication that synchronizes Contacts with another application. To fetch the contacts from the API, I call `me/contacts?select=*`. It returns a list with all contacts but the field `personalNotes` is limited to 256 characters. However I can save more characters without any problems using POST and PATCH requests... Is there a possibility to unlimit this field?

I tried both versions (v1.0 and beta) and didn't find anything useful at google and in the official documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We return the first 256 characters of the Notes for performance reasons, if you want to see the full content of the Notes, then you can do a GET on the individual Contacts. Thanks for your feedback, we will look to see if there's a better way for our API to behave.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, sending over 1000 requests to get all the contact data is not a solution for me. It would be really nice to have a query parameter that returns full entries.

Comment: Good news @dolek, we've made a change to return the full contents of Notes. The change should be deployed and available now. Thanks for using our API and reporting issues.